# Running Qt for WinRT apps in the Windows Phone emulator

Tags: windows-runtime, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator

I set up Visual Studio 2013 Community and Qt SDK 5.5.0 for WinRT. I built the app with the WinRT x86 (Emulator) toolchain.

Now I'd like to try the app in the Emulator but I can't find it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was using virtualized Windows. It's why Hyper-V was unavailable and the virtual machine the same.